# Java Leading Digit Position

Tags: java

I'm trying to find out how to get the leading digit from a number. For instance if I have the number `.004` I want a number signifying the position of the leading digit `'4'` and thus I would get the number `-3`.

How can I do this?

Comment: and what if `1.004` ?

Comment: Are *you* trying to solve it, or are you trying to see if someone will write code for you? Please [edit] your question with your attempts, even if wrong

Comment: what is `.004`? do you mean: `0.004`? by "leading" do you the "the first digit from left to right which is not zero" ?

Answer (score -1):

The function you are looking for might be the logarithm, like `Math.log10()`.

However, it dosn't give you an exact integer position, but magnitude of the number which is a good starting point to go on